# Create Dynamic route and render component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, components, render, dynamic-routing

I am new in ReactJs.
I need a route like localhost:3000/directory/category/region/brandName and for the same route, I need to render a component

Sample of URL be like

1. localhost:3000/directory/photography/france/testA
2. localhost:3000/directory/Catering/germany/testB

for both above URLs, a component called **name.js** should render

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of react-router and then configure your Routes by making use of Route params

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
const App () => {
  return (
     <Router>
       <Switch>
           <Route path="/directory/:profession/:country/:value" component={Name} />
           <Route path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
       </Switch>
  )
}
```

Now post this you can access the params in name component and fetchData from api or have any other logic

```
const Name = () => {
   const { profession, country, value} = useParams();

   useEffect(() => {
       // Any fetch logic based on params
   }, [profession, country, value]);

   return (
       ..
   )
}
```

You can read more about [react-router usage here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts) and also [refer the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the question, you can handle this through using "Redirect" component. Let there be a "Navigation" component where the "Router" is defined as you did

**Navigation.js**

```
import Name from './name';
import From from './from';

<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/from">
       <From />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/directory/:profession/:country/:value">
       <Name />
   </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

and a "From" component where paths and redirections are defined. If "redirectionPath" is not null you can return "Redirect" component in render. Thus, you can redirect to and render the Name component.

**From.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";


class From extends Component {
    state={
        redirectionPath: "/directory/photography/france/testA" // or setState anywhere you need.
    }

    ...

    render(){
        if(this.state.path){
            return (<Redirect to={this.state.redirectionPath} />)
        }
        return (
            <SomeComponent/>
        );
    }
}
```

This can be one of the solutions. Hope it works for you as well.